# Intentando leer una columna con pandas, solo puedo acceder a la primera

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Al leer un archivo csv, me detecta correctamente las columnas en df, pero si quiero acceder individualmente a una que no sea la primera me da error. Pero para la primera columna no hay ningún problema en mostrarla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No es solo para mostrarla, sino para cualquier operación relacionada con la columna.

He visto en otras preguntas lo de incluir el separador `sep=","` ya que yo separo con comas, pero sigue sin funcionar (también he probado a poner `;` como separadores.)

El código es:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv("Archivos_Problemas_Resueltos\\datos.csv", sep=",")

apellidos = df['apellido']
print(apellidos)
```

Y el csv es:

```
"nombre", "apellido", "edad"

"Lucas", "Adrian",91

"Roberto", "Fernandez",42

"Candre", "Sanchez",24

"Nicolas", "Zosten",27
```

Comment: Buenas, Carlota, bienvenida al sitio. Por favor, incluye tu código como texto formateado en lugar de como imagen. Y sería interesante que incluyeras, también como texto, las primeras líneas de tu fichero CSV

Comment: Perdón lo incluyo en el texto arriba!

Comment: ¿Esos espacios luego de las comas en verdad están en el csv?

Comment: Es debido a los espacios en el archivo CSV, utiliza `skipinitialspace=True`.....   df= `pd.read_csv("Archivos_Problemas_Resueltos\\datos.csv", sep="," ,  skipinitialspace=True )`

Comment: Mil gracias!! Solucionado con ese comando!